# Finding a derivative for every X

Tags: integration

I need to find the derivative of this function for every x$\in$R. I tried breaking it down into 2 integrals and using the taylor series but had no luck. Any ideas?

F(x)=$\int$$_0^x$cos$\frac{1}{t-1}$dt

Comment: Use Fundamental Theorem of Calculus.

Answer (score 0):

**Hint:** The fundamental theorem of calculus states that $$\frac d{dx}\left(\int_a^x f(t)\,\mathrm dt \right)= f(x)$$

Comment: What about if x equals 1.

Comment: The derivative at $1$ is not well defined. This makes sense because if the upper limit of the integral was $1$ (or more), then the integral would not be well behaved at $1$ either.

Comment: It scares me how easy it looks. Will keep you posted if I figure anything else out. I mean it says for every real $x$.

Answer (score 0):

This is just the Fundamental Theorem of Calculus:

$$\frac{d}{dx}\int_0^x \cos\frac{1}{t-1}dt = \cos\frac{1}{x-1}$$

Since you're doing Taylor series now, I suspect that you covered this a few months ago in your course; I'd just go back and review old notes.

Comment: I kind of knew I could do that but the thing that bothered me was not having an answer for the derivative in x=1. Might be a dumb thing to say, but I had to ask.